# C#/Unity/Hybrid ECS - Trying to convert GameObject into ECS Entity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-dots

I am Using Unity 2019.2.14f.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Transforms;
using Unity.Collections;

public class GameSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public int spawnNumber;
    public bool useECS;
    private EntityManager manager;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        manager = World.Active.EntityManager;
        if (useECS)
        {
            SpawnECS(player);
        }
            else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= spawnNumber; i++)
            {
                Spawn(player);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void Spawn(GameObject unit)
    {
        float x = Random.Range(5, 249);
        float y = 0f;
        float z = Random.Range(5, 249);
        float rx = 0f;
        float ry = Random.Range(1, 180);
        float rz = 0f;
        Instantiate(unit, new Vector3(x, y, z), Quaternion.Euler(rx,ry,rz));
    }

    private void SpawnECS(GameObject unit)
    {
        float x = Random.Range(5, 249);
        float y = 0f;
        float z = Random.Range(5, 249);
        float rx = 0f;
        float ry = Random.Range(1, 180);
        float rz = 0f;
        NativeArray<Entity> players = new NativeArray<Entity>(spawnNumber, Allocator.Temp);
        manager.Instantiate(unit, players);
        players.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This is the prefab which I am instantiating:

[image]

When I select on my `GameSystem` component `useECS` to be true I can see it is creating enteties into my entity debugger. Take a look:

[image]

So as you can see Entities are created. However when I inspect one Entity here is what I see:
[image]

As you can see Components are not converted. Where is my mistake?
How can I create visible entity out of GameObhject Prefab or use the so-called Hybrid ECS method?

Comment: Did you use the hybrid renderer?

Comment: No, what is that ?

Comment: They introduced the hybrid renderer so you would see your entities...

Answer (score 0):

```
NativeArray<Entity> players = new NativeArray<Entity>( 3 , Allocator.Temp );
```

Is equivalent to writing :

```
var players = new GameObject[]{ new GameObject() , new GameObject() , new GameObject() };
```

It's a list of prefab entities, that are completely empty. This is why spawning that list will give N amount of default entities.

What to should do instead is to convert that player GameObject to an entity prefab and instantiate that entity prefab N times (or populate that NativeArray with set of entity prefabs)

```
Entity entityPrefab = GameObjectConversionUtility.ConvertGameObjectHierarchy( gameObjectPrefab );
```

Comment: **Friendly advice**: Be aware that there is no Animator-equivalent in entities yet. So you probably don't want to use entities until, at least, late 2020. [Job system](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/JobSystem.html) and [Burst](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.burst@0.2/manual/index.html) works already and are very useful when dealing with heavy computations already.